# Hash function on byte arrays, with independent order

Tags: hash

I would like to have a hash function $H(a_1,...,a_n)$ with the following properties:

1. $a_1 ... a_n$ are byte arrays with same size (typically 32 or 64 bytes).
2. It should also allow "easy" update or deletion of a single element, i.e :

   - $H(a_1,...,a_{n+1}) = f(H(a_1,...,a_n), a_{n+1})$
   - $H(a_1,...,a_{i-1},a_{i+1},...,a_n) = g(H(a_1,...,a_{n}), a_i)$
3. The order of the $a_1 ... a_n$ terms for $H$ function does not matter.

I found a similar question, but I don't think it can easily handle the single item deletion requirement: [Is there such thing as an order independent, updatable hash?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51258/is-there-such-thing-as-an-order-independent-updatable-hash)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sort of security requirements does the hash function need to meet?  For example, preimage resistance, modified second preimage resistance, modified collision resistance ("modified" because of the commutative nature of the hash function would give some easy second preimages)?

Comment: Actually, Ethan's hash function (that you linked to) wouldn't be hard to modify to make it be able to handle deletes; you'd select $g$in Ethan's function to have a prime order $q$, and you'd have the $g$ function you asked for in question 2 be $g(H(a_1, ..., a_n), a_i) = H(a_1, ..., a_n)^{SHA256(a_i)^{-1} \bmod q} \bmod p$

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your suggestion this works perfectly!

Comment: Here is a more detailed description of what I'm trying to achieve:

- I have $o_1 ... o_n$ objects in datastore (which are returned in random order).

- Each object $o_i$ is signed in datastore, the signature is $a_i$

- I want to detect "rogue" insertions (can be done with the signatures) and more importantly rogue deletions, so the need for this kind of hash for this purpose.

Comment: What I'm not sure is how to select a "good" $g$ value of prime order $q$. I basically use this algorithm:

- Step 1: Generate a prime number $q$

- Step 2: Compute $p = 2q + 1$

- Step 3: Choose a random $h$ and compute $g = h^{(p-1)/q} (mod p)$

- Step 4: if $g^q (mod p) =1$ then keep $p$, $g$ and $q$ otherwise go to step 1

By the way, what would be a good size for the $q$ parameter ?

Comment: Still unsure what security properties you're hoping to achieve here.  Not even really sure what the modular exponentiation adds.  From the information available, it sounds like you could make do by just combining the SHA-256 hashes with some abelian group operation, _e.g._ addition in $\mathbb Z/2^{256}\mathbb Z$ or $\operatorname{GF}(2^{256})$ (_i.e._, xor) or $\operatorname{GF}(2^{127} - 1)$, or multiplication in the latter two.

Comment: @user1563703: the easiest way might be to select $p = 2q+1$, with $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ and that both $p$ and $q$ are prime; then, $g=2$ will have order $q$.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage: as for what the modular exponentiation adds, well, that's a good question.  If you need (modified) second preimage resistance, the modexp is actually irrelevant.  If wouldn't do addition in $GF(2^{256})$ if you need any security property; addition in $\mathbb{Z}/2^{1024}$ (with a large hash function, such as SHAKE) might be interesting...

Comment: If I use the "xor" with the SHA-256 hashes, I think an attacker could repeat some elements, as $a_1$ xor ... xor $a_n$ xor $a_j$ xor $a_j$ = $a_1$ xor ... xor $a_n$.

Comment: @user1563703 Yes.  Can you articulate the security properties you hope to achieve that would exclude xor?